# Importing org.apache.commons into android applications

Tags: java, android, import

Hay, how do i import org.apache.commons packages into android so i can use them in my applications?

Thanks

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method/8287154) if you run into NoSuchMethodError at runtime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using eclipse:

1. Download jar packages for libraries you are interested in
2. Go to project properties in eclipse -> Java Build Path -> Libraries. Add External JARs here.

Comment: On OS X using Eclipse i don't have an "eclipse" menu item. any ideas?

Comment: Scrap that, i found it. Life saver, thank you very much Nikola.

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness' sake - if you aren't using eclipse to develop and you are building with ant - just put the jar in your libs folder of your project.
Done!

Answer (score 3):

Also, be warned that not all of them can be automatically converted to Dalvik. For example commons-httpclient does not convert cleanly from the release binaries, you need to go through source to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using android Stuido - that doesn't yet supports adding libraries - you need to edit the src/build.gradle

I wanted to add org.apache.commons.net and My file called 'org.apache.commons.net.jar' was placed in the libs folder, so my build.gradles dependencies look now like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.net.jar')
}
```