# Is there a htmlDecode?

Tags: android

I am downloading a JSONObject from a web site. The entries are however HTML-encoded, using

```
&quot;
```

and

```
&#038;
```

tags. Is there an easy way to get these to Java strings? Short of writing the converter myself, of course.

Thanks RG

PS: I am using the stuff in a ListView. Probably I can use Html.fromHTML as I can for TextView. Don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I simply went to write my own quick fix. Not efficient, but that's OK for the purpose. A 5-minutes-solution.

```
public static String unescape (String s)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int n=s.indexOf("&#");
        if (n<0) break;
        int m=s.indexOf(";",n+2);
        if (m<0) break;
        try
        {
            s=s.substring(0,n)+(char)(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(n+2,m)))+
                s.substring(m+1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
    s=s.replace("&quot;","\"");
    s=s.replace("&lt;","<");
    s=s.replace("&gt;",">");
    s=s.replace("&amp;","&");
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of success in using the Apache Commons on Android.

You should be able to use [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String)) (from the [Lang package](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)).

Here are the (fairly straightforward) directions on using the Apache Commons libraries in your Android apps: [Importing org.apache.commons into android applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146870/importing-org-apache-commons-into-android-applications).