# Html string in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an string which is as below

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;table border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;
&lt;tbody&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;enter code here
&lt;td&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Ut imperdiet tortor sit amet enim bibendum eget fermentum lectus auctor.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Cras mattis mi nec dolor iaculis a rhoncus ligula lacinia.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Phasellus sit amet lorem ut nunc iaculis lacinia nec at diam.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Duis nec turpis ac diam vehicula malesuada.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Ut imperdiet tortor sit amet enim bibendum eget fermentum lectus auctor.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Cras mattis mi nec dolor iaculis a rhoncus ligula lacinia.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Phasellus sit amet lorem ut nunc iaculis lacinia nec at diam.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Duis nec turpis ac diam vehicula malesuada.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/tbody&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum sem ante, scelerisque vehicula libero. Sed porttitor tincidunt lacus, et lacinia mauris placerat at. Fusce laoreet scelerisque turpis sit amet dignissim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mollis, urna sed adipiscing posuere, erat orci facilisis neque, quis fringilla ipsum neque ut libero. Sed eget arcu massa, sodales fermentum lorem. Morbi fringilla commodo magna lobortis porttitor. Etiam tortor elit, cursus non placerat vel, dapibus vitae velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam euismod nisl vitae orci viverra imperdiet.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I want to show all this with out HTML tag .

Please help me ...
and kindly suggest me to do in any way if you can.

Comment: try textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("yourstring");

Comment: If you are trying to remove the htmlEncoding, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/3962884/759019

Comment: @MSingh Please see my answer and if you have any query then tell me.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya I'm pretty sure the OP will get notified of a new answer to their question. There is no need to comment as well. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make it in real HTML i.e. <> then remove the HTML tag with regex.

```
mTextView.setText(HTML.fromHtml("&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;L...." ));
String regexNoHTML = "\\<.*?\\>";    
String finalStringNoHTML = mTextView.getText.replaceAll(noHTMLString, "");
mTextView.setText(finalStringNoHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks hotveryspicy

Specialist suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Html.fromHtml(yourHtml)`..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can assign like below

```
txtUpgrade.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.upgrade_text)));
```

Answer (score 0):

First store your string value into one variable and then use below code for display this this string into textview.

```
String s="&lt;li&gt;Duis nec turpis ac diam vehicula malesuada.&lt;/li&gt;";
mTxtView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Comment: Thanks Dipak 
but i tried it ,

not working
changing &lt; to < only i mean to say only changing html text to symbol