# Convert HTML symbol to Java symbol

Tags: java, html, unicode

How can i convert HTML symbol to Java symbol? For example: I have `&#xe000` `String` and i need Java `char` like `\ue000`. What i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better solution in Android. I just call static method `Html.fromHtml("&#xe000")`, and the given result wat another `String` in Java source format like `\ue000`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`unescapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) from the Apache Commons toolkit.

Comment: How can i use it in Android, i need to install some additional library?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146870/importing-org-apache-commons-into-android-applications. Yes, it's an additional library, but it has so much useful stuff you'll want to keep using it ;)