# Eclipse is not importing jar dependencies between two projects in the same workspace

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is the situation.

I have a java project "LicenseGenerator" in eclipse that depends on commons-codec.  I have therefore added the commons-codec jar file to the build path.  I have Junit tests and everything is working fine.

I have made a different project in the same workspace - which happens to be an Android project - that needs to use my LicenseGenerator classes.  I added LicenseGenerator to the "projects" tab in the build path - the classes were recognized and I was able to use them.

Everything compiled and ran. However, when the part of the LicenseGenerator that used the commons-codec was called from my Android project I got the following error.

> Could not find method
>   org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString,
>   referenced from method

This basically tells me that the commons-codec was not packaged which the Android project, so I added the commons-codec to the android project as well but the same error appears.

how do I fix this?
[alt text http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec5.png](http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec5.png)

[alt text http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec4.png](http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec4.png)

[alt text http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec1.png](http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec1.png)

[alt text http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec3.png](http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec3.png)

[alt text http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec2.png](http://droidprofessor.com/trash/commons-codec2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Order and Export` tab of the `Build Path` dialog, and check the libraries that you want to export as dependencies of other projects.

> Exported entries are contributed to dependent projects

Comment: I did that and it still does not work.  I ticked the box next to commons-codec in the java build path for LicenseGenerator.  I also tried moving it to the top.

Comment: Still not working.  I selected Project-->Clean, then ticked both projects.

Comment: Give 2 screenshots of the two important tabs - the project dependency and the order & export.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a problem with the Android API

[Apache Commons Codec with Android: could not find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method)