# Alternative of DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byte[] array) and DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(String str) in Android

Tags: android, string, arrays, type-conversion

what are the alternative of `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byte[] array)` and  `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(String str)` in Android.  Android don't have classDef of `java.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`...

Comment: you will need to add javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.jar in your project . you can download it from http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

Comment: i have added java.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter it is not working.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  this library it is not working!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably better off using the hexadecimal encoding/decoding found in the Apache [commons codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/). Please make sure you are using the correct version of the library though, for more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method)

Comment: This convinced me that using the commons codec library will make the world a better place:

"At the time of Codec's proposal, there were approximately 34 different Java classes that dealt with Base64 encoding spread over the [Apache] Foundation's CVS repository...  Out of that confusing duplication of effort sprang this simple attempt to encourage code reuse among various projects."

Comment: Here's the maven repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec

Comment: commons-codec was already included in one of the dependencies of my project.  Didn't even need to add a dependency!  

Comment: The original implementation, if it helps anyone convert their code to commons-codec: https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-spec/blob/master/jaxb-api/src/main/java/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverterImpl.java

Comment: @GlenPeterson This should be an answer (as you initially tried) or a comment *under the question* but linking to the source of `DataTypeConverterImpl` has preciously little to do with my answer above. I'd also shorten the link description, as it is unclear what you're linking to this way (SE shortens the link description by removing the last part). So thanks for trying to improve the information here, but could you please put it elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

For android (gradle) dependencies just use

```
implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.12-b140109.1041'
implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.12.0'
```