# Can't figure out how to reconcile exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String

Tags: java, android, nosuchmethoderror

I'm running my Android app (which worked fine until I added a basic authentication call) and even though Eclipse has no problem including the lib in the project, when I run the apk, it throws

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String
```

I have tried adding the .jar in properties, checking the jar off in the "export" tab... nothing seems to help.

I've never had this problem before and am using another Commons jar in this same project which works perfectly.

What might I be overlooking that it would fail to include this jar in the compiled apk?

The .jar file is sitting in the libs directory, along with the other ones (which are being included).

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method) will help you? Oh! just saw CommonsWare comment which points to the same link, sorry!

Comment: Yes, thanks @CommonsWare, that was precisely it.  Odd that I didn't find that SO question on my own, I tried a few variations on the theme.