# Is there any difference between Apache's Base64.encodeBase64 and Android's Base64.encode with Base64.Default flag?

Tags: java, android, base64, apache-commons

Sample A (using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64):

```
Base64.encodeBase64("foobar".getBytes());
```

Sample B (using android.util.Base64):

```
Base64.encode("foobar".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Do these produce the same string?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

No, the difference is that with the default settings, Android's Base64 includes line terminators. To obtain the same result as with the Apache encoding, use Base64.NO_WRAP.

Comment: Does the same hold for android.util.Base64.decode() ?