# Gradle :app:preDexDebug error Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm writing an app with Android platform, In my app im using some external jars, due to some errors connected with version of common codecs in android SDK I had to change one of functions in external jar like here [Apache Commons Codec with Android: could not find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method/2533538#2533538) and export project to new jar file. I have deleted old jar file from android project i have cleaned build added new jar file and now all the time i recieve such an error :

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Maybe `build clean` does not work as I think it should and it does not delete old version of jar file?

Comment: Can you share the code of build.gradle (module) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is compiling. Change compile options to Java 6.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the jdk version to 1.7:
for change go to Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK Location.
this is work for me. I hope work for you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of clues, actually what i had to do was, in eclipse set jdk to 1.7 and recompile it with such settings then add it do android project.