# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I'm trying to use [Firebase token generator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-java) but I always get this error

```
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString
```

I use commons codec 1.10. I don't know whether is there a conflict or not. I'm just lost.

Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Android are you using? Android already includes an older version of commons-codec:

[Discussion about this problem](http://blog.osom.info/2015/04/commons-codec-on-android.html)

Also here: [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method)

You are talking about:

```
encodeBase64URLSafeString
```

The method is since 1.4:

[1.10 commons-codec Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafeString%28byte[]%29)

In this Firebase token generator I can see:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I guess you probably have an older version on the classpath then.

Comment: no I use the newest version 1.10 and also I tried 1.7 ... it gives me same error