# encodeBase64URLSafeString()? Is this a real method?

Tags: android, encoding, base64, jakarta-mail

I am trying to make an Android app that can send an email. I have imported javax mail api and I am using it to try to create a Message to send. In the example I am following to make mine I have seen a method used:

```
String encodeMail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
```

When I try to use this method it is not found. And when searching for it online I don't find it. Any idea how to access it? Or at least to achieve the same thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533538/5284441

Comment: I don't know what you're using that method for, but you shouldn't need to use it to encode any part of an email message.