# After trying to decode Base64, reciving E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons-codec

I´m building a simple app for android 4.4 and up, i have a method to decode base64 string using the apache-commons-codec library.

```java
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public static String decodeBase64(String toDecode) {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(toDecode);

    return new String(decoded);
}
```

but when i call this static method from the main (like className.decodeBase64(VAR)) I receive the following error.
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44gHD.png)

i'm currently using jdk 8 and the last version of android studio. 
I know that the jdk8 implements a base64 encoder/decoder but i can´t use it, because I was limited to programming to more recent android versions at 8.0

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the library version. Which version of `commons-codec` do you use in your `build.gradle` file? 
Try updating it to the latest, which is `1.13`.
Also this may be the solution for your issue:
[Apache Commons Codec with Android: could not find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the response, i already try it. not working neither. the second option that i try was importing the jar file from Comms to the project. but dont work

Answer (score 0):

After two days looking for it, i find a nice solution.

Just need to replace the apache.commons with android.util.Base64, who'd say...

the method would look like the following:

```
import android.util.Base64;

public static String DecodeBase64(String toDecode){
    byte[] decodeValue = Base64.decode(toDecode, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return new String(decodeValue);
}
```

also, if someone knows how to solve the original error and please explain me why that happen, it would be helpful